# Is using "however" appropriate in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

"His experience, however small it is, is worth listening to."

In this sentence, what I am trying to say is basically his experience is little but what he says is important. So we should listen to it. Does "however" make sense here? It is supposed to explain the quantitative property or the extent of the object. Another example could be: "The sun however big it is, is still smaller than many stars."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of "however" here is appropriate and I believe the sentence is grammatical as you've written it.
However, I think it would be more natural to omit "it is":
"His experience, however small, is worth listening to"